# How do you know Brahman is the cause of the universe vs a Jain model

Tags: brahman

lets say that the soul has always existed apart from the 5 elements individually but that the elements and the souls were always there?like the Jains believe.how can you claim Brahman is the material cause for the universe against such a model?what if the universe simply always existed,and the souls existed individually always.

how can you argue against such a view?

if matter has always existed seperately from the souls,then brahman is not needed as a cause of matter.Also,you cannot assert that the souls are one.they could be individual.

Comment: "How  can you argue against such a view? Well, the hindus do not accept that view. The scriptures state that the brahman always existed and that he vreated the material world.

Comment: Jains do not follow the Vedas. Vedantists follow the Vedas. The proof of Brahman is in the Vedas. There is no way to reconcile the two views as they are founded on two different authorities.